# Why won't JRD MMITest go away?

Tags: applications

This app (which doesn't actually appear to exist on my phone) keeps popping up randomly on my phone. Its called JRD MMITest and seems to want to test the functionality of the phone.

It covers such tests as accelerometer, touch screen, radio, speaker, bluetooth, wifi, etc but all of that works fine without the app even testing for it.

In what I suspect is a related issue, certain phone features have also turned off from time to time... Auto Rotation being one of them and I noticed my Play Store app's data had suddenly been restricted on wifi. I have since corrected these issues with no further anomalies becoming evident as yet.

My phone is a Vodafone Smart 4 Mini (Model Number 785) running Android Jellybean 4.2.2.

I've completed the testing successfully and restarted the phone under the impression that this would prevent it from coming up again. (as per [Annoying MMI test on Alcatel one touch evolve?](https://support.t-mobile.com/thread/76365)) however the app keeps coming up randomly.

I don't know what else to do here, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I have done some researches and found that some carriers add this test on their devices. However, I didn't found anything to remove/ignore this test.

Comment: Had to factory reset my phone to get it to go away

Answer (score 1):

According to [tnagy](http://www.webanswers.com/technology-computers/what-does-jrd-mmitest-do-on-my-alcatel-one-touch-990-2b2309) on the topic of JRD MMITest:

> This is the manufacture test of your Android phone's internal components. It will perform a check on the main components like LCD display, sound, etc.

You should be able to **disable** the app if you do not want this app to perform regular checks.

1. From **Settings > Apps**, slide all the way to the right until you see the *all* apps screen (not *downloaded* or *running*). Scroll down to **MMI Test** and click on it. *Note: On some devices it might be listed as **MMI Test II**, or some other derivative.*
2. After clicking **MMI Test** in your list of all apps, you should be able to **Disable** the app. This will keep the app on the phone, but it will not be able to run at all, even in the background.

If you want to permanently remove the app, you can **root** your phone and install an app like [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), which can delete system apps, such as **MMI Test**.

Comment: The "Disable" button is... disabled. Irony :)

Comment: @WindRider In some cases, the manufacturer may not allow you to disable an important app to prevent breaking your device. One common example is the "Setup" app. It seems that the manufacturer does not allow you to disable the app. The only way to override this restriction is by rooting your device and using system privileged to either freeze or remove the app.

Comment: I already know this but is there some way to stop this freaking thing!? It appears every 2 seconds!  Basically on every activity startup! I should try to pass all these tests.